# Should I put a HDD or SSD into the CD Caddy?

Tags: laptop

For my company laptop Dell M4700 I will get a HDD Caddy for its CD bay.
Then I have one mSATA SSD, one HDD one normal SSD inside.

Should I put the SSD or the HDD into the CD bay HDD Caddy?
I will leave it this way, no changes to CD intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your intended uses for the workstation.

According to 4700 spec sheet the ODD bay is SATA2 max, so putting SSD there is actually a waste of the bandwidth. But, since you're already riding mSATA SSD in it you won't feel any difference, as mSATA on 4700 is SATA2 only, too.

My recommendation would be to put one SSD in HDD bay and using it for OS, and the rest however you'll like.

Answer (score 1):

It probably does not matter at all on an M4700, as the system is specifically designed around an assumption that someone may want to put an HDD in place of the DVD.  (In some other systems it might make sense to put the HDD in the CD Bay because it might have a slower bus, conversely it may make sense to switch it arround if the had drive bay is located more centrally in the computer to reduce risk of damage - but as its on the edge on the M4700, I doubt it makes a difference)